# cabin fan motor loud then burnt out

Tags: ford, belt, fan

I figured out that my fan mower's bearing were going out by the loud screeching it made.

Being lazy I ignored it.

Then one day I was sitting at a light and the cabin filled with horrible smoke. I can hear an additional belt as it struggles. I can use it just long enough to defrost.

I quess my question is, will doing this for a few weeks until I can repair it cause any other permanent damage?

2002 Taurus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have partially answered this yourself- you are seeing smoke, which implies the bearings are getting hot.

So they could start a fire. Or in seizing up the fan could cause your wiring to catch fire. Or you could end up with a cabin full of dangerous fumes... etc

You could do permanent damage, yes. Pay close attention and you might be okay.

Personally, I'd just get it fixed.

Comment: Being lazy often leads to much more expensive repairs down the road.  Best to take care of issues right away while they're small.  Well, unless you're rich and your time is worth more than a few hundred or thousand dollars here and there.

Comment: eh. just got my new headlight... now the engine is making funny "sizzling" noises. working too much. maybe I will just torch it after pooping in it.